# Вопрос по MySQL с PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Объясните, в чем отличие этого:

```
$query = $bds->query("SELECT balance FROM users WHERE vk_id='$getUID'");
$getBalance = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$getIt = $getBalance[0] - $getCost;  
$bds->query("UPDATE users SET balance=balance-'$getIt' WHERE vk_id='$getUID'");
```

От этого:

```
$bds->query("UPDATE users SET balance=balance-'$getCost' WHERE vk_id='$getUID'");
```

Проблема в том, что если я использую первый способ, то в бд пишется некорректное значение, которое находится в `$getCost`.

*(например, значение **7.88**. т.е. **100 - 7.88**, например, ну никак не может быть равно **7.88**)*.

Во втором случае все отлично, но интересует первый случай.

Comment: Начните с того, что собирайте запрос не в операторе вызова, а в отдельной переменной. Смотрите (и показывайте тут), что именно собралось.

Comment: И потом - ну как-то имена полей и операция вычитания намекают на то, что поля числовые... какого хрена используемые/подставляемые значения обрамляются кавычками, словно это строки?

Answer (score 1):

Балда я..ошибку в лоб не увидел. Вопрос решил. Вместо

```
$bds->query("UPDATE users SET balance=balance-'$getIt' WHERE vk_id='$getUID'");
```

надо было

```
$bds->query("UPDATE users SET balance='$getIt' WHERE vk_id='$getUID'");
```